# Build error of Google Cardboard SDK for Unity Demo in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

I'm trying to build DemoScene of [Google Cardboard SDK for Unity](https://developers.google.com/cardboard/unity/) in Xcode to run it my iPhone 6 Plus.

But it doesn't work, though I could make it worked on Unity and Android.

Did anybody try and make it?
Any advice is really welcome.

error message is as follows.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_InitFromUnity", referenced from:
      RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google Cardboard SDK(Unity Plugin) works only for Android.

Answer (score 2):

While it's true that the Google Cardboard Unity plugin does not support iOS, it still should not fail to compile. The problem appears to be some stray reference to a DLL not actually included with the package (probably used by Google's team internally?).

I have a project where I want the Cardboard plugin for Android but also need to support other platforms (using other input modes), and I hacked a solution like so:

In Cardboard/Scripts/Cardboard.cs, change this set of lines...

```
#if UNITY_IPHONE && !UNITY_EDITOR
  [DllImport("__Internal")]
#else
  [DllImport("RenderingPlugin")]
#endif
  private static extern void InitFromUnity(int textureID);
```

...to this...

```
#if UNITY_IPHONE && !UNITY_EDITOR
    private static void InitFromUnity(int textureID) {}
#else
    [DllImport("RenderingPlugin")]
    private static extern void InitFromUnity(int textureID);
#endif
```

The end result should be a dummy function which doesn't connect to a DLL instead of an external function connected to a DLL which doesn't exist. The Cardboard plugin still DOES NOT WORK on iOS, but you can COMPILE again without having to remove it from the project entirely.

Maybe in the future Google can correct this (not sure off hand where the appropriate place to report it is...?) or even add iOS support (if we're lucky).

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the Durovis Unity plugin. It works perfectly fine with iOS. Just had to comment out two lines which reference some Android specific stuff. Just build an run and you will see which lines you have to comment out.

You can get it here: http://www.durovis.com/sdk.html